# tag based subscription

Tags: tags, email, notifications, subscription

I have different tags based on products, I want that when new post published then only attached tag's subscribed people will get mail.

If this is possible with category then I am fine with changed my functionality.

Comment: How do your users subscribe the tags?

Comment: I am thinking about same. @huraji

Comment: You could create a kind of form to make users subscribe your tags and store them like `user_meta`. Then create your mail function.